# Asp.net page routing not working

Tags: asp.net, routes

I am trying to add page routing (I use regular asp.net 4.0, not mvc), so that when a user goes to:

http://sitename.com/public/member/view/andrey

they would get to:
http://sitename.com/public/memberprofile.aspx?userName=andrey

I added following in Global.asax:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("MemberViewRoute",
        "Public/View/Member/{username}",
        "~/Public/MemberProfile.aspx");
}
```

But when I try going to http://sitename.com/public/member/view/andrey in my browser, I get 404

Is there anything else that needs to be done for this routing to work other than adding a page route map?

Thanks!

Comment: You've got "member" and "view" around the wrong way in the URL string pattern of the route that you are mapping compared to the URL you are trying in the browser

Comment: Did you add it to your map before or after your default handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found this great article that helped me fix my problem: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjacobs/archive/2010/06/30/system-web-routing-routetable-not-working-with-iis.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Your route says `Public/View/Member/{username}`
But your link is `/public/member/view/andrey`

This would definitely 404

Why not try and change your route to

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("MemberViewRoute",
        "Public/Member/View/{username}",
        "~/Public/MemberProfile.aspx");
}
```

and see what happens

Comment: Good catch, but it still hasn't worked. As I found, I needed to add HTTP redirect feature to IIS and a handler entry to web.config